# How to launch unit tests under EclEmma without using the VisualVM launcher with that launcher installed

Tags: eclipse, visualvm, eclemma

I recently installed the "VisualVM Launcher" into my Eclipse IDE.  After using that launcher to help profile some problems in my application, I tried to switch all of my configurations back to using the previous setup.  However, whenever I launch my unit tests using "Coverage As -> JUnit Plug-in Test", it still seems to try to use the VisualVM launcher.

I don't see a place on the "Coverage Configurations" to specify which launcher to use.  If I navigate to the preference page for default launchers ("Run/Debug -> Launching -> Default Launchers"), the [Debug] and [Run] modes under "JUnit Plug-in Test" are both set to use "JUnit Plugin Test Launcher".

Is there some other place where I can set the launcher for running "JUnit Plug-in Tests" under the test coverage tool (EclEmma)?

Version of Eclipse:  Juno Service Release 1

Comment: Looks like many people (including me) are facing this issue. https://github.com/jacoco/eclemma/issues/112

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too have encountered this issue and have found no acceptable solution.

I know it is not much of an answer but I ended up uninstalling VisualVM and resorting to reinstalling it when I need it, for the duration I need.

Comment: This led me to the idea to copy another executable (true.exe from cygwin) to my <JDK_installation>\bin\jvisualvm...NOT.exe, so I can easily append / remove the "...NOT" in Preferences / Run/Debug / Launching / VisualVM Configuration / VisualVM Executable. Note that when not using the file dialog, the text field needs to lose focus for the OK button to get active.